# sibling element affects div visibility

Tags: css

I am creating content div's but they currently aren't visible because a sibling div is overriding it. How can i fix this?

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->
/* parent */
#game {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
/* sibling */
#screen {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden
}
/* div currently not visible */
.tabcontent {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 320px;
  height: 515px;
  background: #191919;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `<div>` being in front of another one, you have 2 solutions

- In your HTML code, put the `.tabcontent` div **after** the `#screen` one, so it will appear in front
- You can use the `z-index` CSS property (which also requires `position`) in order to fix the draw order (which div is in front of which one)

Example for the latter:

```css
#screen {
    position: relative; /* Needed by z-index but won't actually do anything */
    z-index: 0;
}

.tabcontent {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

A greater `z-index` means it will be in front of elements with a lower `z-index`.

Answer (score 0):

Make the parent

```
#game {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

This should bring it to the front